# What is the best way to join 2 records in Pascal?

Tags: list, pascal, records

I've a little problem with records in Pascal. I'm writting a program where I've got two lists of records: one with patients and second with diseases but I don't have idea how to join it. I was trying to do a dynamic table with diseases id's in patient list but lazarus had problems with compiling it. I would be glad if someone helps me.

Comment: What do you mean with "joining records"? Are you talking about the data strucutre "record" or database records? Could you please clarify your question?

Comment: I was talking about data structre "record". Finally I used dynamic table of diseases id's in pacient record but when I was debugging code I found that lazarus 'sigsegv' problem was with dispose function used in procedure which writes records to file.

Comment: sigsegv can mean anything, from bugs in Lazarus, to, more likely, bugs in your code or usage.

Comment: Could you possibly mean 'link' instead of 'join'?

Answer (score 0):

One patient can have many diseases, and many patients can have one disease.

If records about patients describe patients  (e.g. Date of Birth)
and records about diseases describe diseases (e.g. incidence of fatality)
then you need a third list of records about each patient's history with each disease (e.g. date of recovery).

It's not hard to link this third list of records back to patients, using patientid as the guide, and back to diseases, using diseaseid as the guide.

Now you have to do a three way join in order to get all the related information together.

If I had to do this I would use SQL rather than Pascal.  But then there's the overhead of uisng a database.